# how to compare the performance of linear regression vs tree-based methods such as randomforest

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, random-forest, model-evaluation

When I have linear regression, negative binomial, ridge/lasso regression and randomforest, how can I compare their performances?

I've read that between linear regression and ridge/lasso, one can compare r squared, AIC, BIC. And for model comparison in general one can use mean residual deviance.

How can I extract mean residual deviance from lm() in R? and what is the best metrics to compare and evaluate these models?

Comment: Have you tried `logLik`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute mean-squared-error (MSE) or mean-absolute-error (MAE) using a labeled testset. Lower error = better